# PDO prepared statements inserting NULL value into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

Here I have a basic sign up form.

```
<form name="signUp" id="signUp" method="POST" action="insertUser.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>Name</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="signUpName" placeholder="Name"/></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                   <td>Email</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="signUpEmail" placeholder="Email"/></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                   <td>Password</td>
                   <td><input type="password" name="signUpPassword" placeholder="password"/></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </form>
```

Which sends field data to a file `insertUser.php`.

```
  <?php

 include 'User.php';

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user = new User();

    $user->setUserName($_POST['signUpName']);
    $user->setUserEmail($_POST['signUpEmail']);
    $user->setUserPassword($_POST['signUpPassword']);
    $user->userInsert();


 }

?>
```

That file creates an object of a class named `User` and passes the data received from the form to the variables of that class. The `userInsert` function of the `User` class finally inserts the data into the database.

```
<?php

     class User{

        public $userName, $userEmail, $userPassword;

        public function getUserName(){
            return $this->userName;
        }

        public function setUserName($userName){
            $this->userName = $userName;
        }

        public function getUserEmail(){
            return $this->userEmail;
        }

        public function setUserEmail($userEmail){
            $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
        }

        public function getUserPassword(){
            return $this->userPassword;
        }

        public function setUserPassword($userPassword){
            $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
        }


     public function userInsert(){

        global $userName, $userEmail, $userPassword;

        include 'db_connection.php';

         $r = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user(Username, Useremail, Userpassword) VALUES(:userName, :userEmail, :userPassword);");
         $r->bindParam(':userName',$userName);
         $r->bindParam(':userEmail',$userEmail);
         $r->bindParam(':userPassword',$userPassword);
         $r->execute();

         header('Location: index.php?successful=1');

        }

}
```

DB connection

```
<?php

        try{
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basicchatapp","root","");
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die("Error: ");
        }

?>
```

Now problem is, each time it is inserting `NULL` input.

Searched lot other answers, but none of the solutions worked for me. Getting a hint will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: You're also bizarrely mixing object-oriented style and the legacy procedural variant meant for backwards compatibility, not new code. You also don't need to do things like `== TRUE` most of the time. Check the function. Many are designed to return logically *truthful* things.

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much for pointing out these crucial issues in my code. But I am not getting actually what is making it to insert blank data into database when I`m checking for empty fields. It is inserting, but all blank rows.

Comment: " legacy procedural " do you call all procedural code legacy @tadman?

Comment: @nogad I'm calling the `mysql_query` style interface a concession to legacy code, plus PHP 4 which didn't support objects. `mysqli` itself is a bit of a legacy support feature. PDO should be used whenever practical if not something better.

Comment: all good, just curious @tadman

Answer (score 0):

May be your userInsert() function not found the variable value so pass the those parameter in function then it should look like below code

```
 class User{

    public $userName, $userEmail, $userPassword;

    public function getUserName(){
        return $this->userName;
    }

    public function setUserName($userName){
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }

    public function getUserEmail(){
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    public function setUserEmail($userEmail){
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
    }

    public function getUserPassword(){
        return $this->userPassword;
    }

    public function setUserPassword($userPassword){
        $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
    }


    public function userInsert($userName=null,$userEmail=null,$userPassword=null){
        include 'db_connection.php';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user(Username, Useremail, Userpassword) VALUES($userName,$userEmail,$userPassword);";

        if(mysqli_query($db,$sql) == TRUE){
            header('Location: index.php?successful=1');
        }
        else{
            header('Location: index.php?successful=0');
        } 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your query with this

$sql = "INSERT INTO user(Username, Useremail, Userpassword) VALUES('$this->userName','$this->userEmail','$this->userPassword');";

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. Btw later on I was trying to use PDO with prepared statements but now it is inserting 'NULL' values in database. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Please share the code with me then i can tell you easily, Thanks

Comment: <?php

        try{
          $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basicchatapp","root","");
          $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die("Error: ");
        }

?>

Comment: public function userInsert(){

            global $userName, $userEmail, $userPassword;

       include 'db_connection.php';

             $r = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user(Username, Useremail, Userpassword) VALUES(:userName, :userEmail, :userPassword);");
             $r->bindParam(':userName',$userName);
             $r->bindParam(':userEmail',$userEmail);
             $r->bindParam(':userPassword',$userPassword);
             $r->execute();

             header('Location: index.php?successful=1');

         }

Comment: Thanks man I have fixed it. Thank you so much for your effort. :-)

Comment: It ok,Keep it up